# Error while Importing data in Sqoop 2 (Hue 3.6) using custom SQL

Tags: sqoop, hue

In Hue 3.6 I'm trying to use Sqoop 2 import feature for a custom SQL query from an Oracle database.
I'm pasting the SQL query in the field "Table SQL statement" for example: "SELECT x,y,z FROM myschema.mytable where a > 100"

I'm getting the following exception "SQL statement must contain placeholder for auto generated conditions - ${CONDITIONS}"

1. I need to understand how to use ${CONDITIONS} when running the Hue UI?
2. Is there any demo, documentation available on using Sqoop 2 
   from Hue with some advanced features like using custom SQL etc.?

I'm using Cloudera Sandbox that is using Hue 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify condition like following :

```
"SELECT x,y,z FROM myschema.mytable where a > 100 AND ${CONDITIONS}"
```

In sqoop2 [code](https://github.com/cloudera/sqoop2/blob/cdh5-1.99.3_5.1.3/connector/connector-generic-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/sqoop/connector/jdbc/GenericJdbcImportInitializer.java#L192) it searches for ' ${CONDITIONS} ' token and throws exception if it doesn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the DOCS [Free-Form Queries on SQOOP](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1763872). Be careful when you use double quotes "", you have to add the `\$CONDITIONS`. If you query with single quotes you only need to add  `$CONDITIONS` without backslash.

Comment: I forgot  to say that , during the execution of the  **free form query** command the _\$CONDITIONS_ field add  the following :  (1=0). So the query converted to `SELECT x,y,z FROM myschema.mytable where a > 100 AND (1=0)`.